# When close vote, why can we migrate the question only to meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, migration

When I [review Close Votes](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats), I often want to migrate the question to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) because it is not specific to Raspberry Pi. But the only site I can migrate to is [Meta RPi.SE](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).[image]

Sometimes, it is even not possible to migrate the question at all.[image]

Is it privilege related? Or the feature is not yet implemented? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the site is still in Beta.  Beta sites can only migrate to their own meta.

Most beta sites have had this question asked at some time or another.  There is a more general answer on  [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68000/allow-beta-sites-to-migrate-questions-to-relevant-sites) .