# Suggestions for update to `Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration` page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging, migration

Some questions here are definitely better fits for other SE sites as they have no special relevance to the Raspberry Pi. I think this comment is more or less generally accepted. At stands now, however, there's no way to systematically recommend migration during the flagging process. Our current list of possible sites during the flagging interview is just our own meta site.

I see two related questions to this going back several years, and I understand that the answer to "Why is it like this?" at that time was that the site was still beta and therefore not eligible to migrate. I believe that not longer applies, right? I used the other question, which had some suggested migration paths to build a current list that I'd like to propose for implementation.

- [What should our off-topic migration paths be?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330/what-should-our-off-topic-migration-paths-be)
- [When close vote, why can we migrate the question only to meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/501/when-close-vote-why-can-we-migrate-the-question-only-to-meta-raspberrypi-stacke)

Drawing from the past discussion, I would like to suggest that these migration paths be added:

- Stack Overflow (general programming) https://stackoverflow.com/
- Unix & Linux SE https://unix.stackexchange.com/
- Electrical Engineering SE https://electronics.stackexchange.com/
- Super User (general home networking and administration) https://superuser.com/

I'm under the impression that we can have 4 sites plus our own meta, so this is my prioritized list of 4. I could have added a couple more if the limit was higher.

Is this list appropriate?  If so, what needs to happen to have it implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skimming through the *moderator only* list of migrations I tend to agree that the main paths to migrate posts away are indeed SO, U&L, and EE. Superuser is is less common and is more or less on a par with Arduino, Robotics, and Hardware Recommendations. IoT has been a target three times lately.

It is however noteworthy that migration really is not something that happens very often. To give an impression: the last five migrations (away) have been on: May 18, May 22, July 10, August 1, September 9.

As I understand it there is no tool for community or moderators to set those migration paths up. Instead we would need to reach out for the community managers to implement it. Which they do only if necessary, read: "when the frequency of migration is creating a burden for the source site" (stolen from [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/90591)). That's not the case here too given the number of migrations as shown above.

Concerning migrations it is noteworthy that (same source):

> Generally we only migrate a question when it's well-formed but blatantly off-topic here, and also blatantly on-topic somewhere else. If it's a junk question it gets closed, if it's on-topic here, it doesn't matter if it's on-topic somewhere else too. It stays here (especially if it's been answered).

So, where to go from that?

1. Use comments to guide the OP of the respective question, i.e. suggesting to post someplace else if you have reason to believe that question is a good fit for the other site. (Here it is necessary to remember that questions can very well be on topic on more than one site, if it is on topic here, no need to send it away.) This (in theory) includes that the OP checks the target site for any dupes to their question first (being shot down upon arrival is the sad fate of many migrations). Obviously the original post needs to be closed (close vote or flag) here.
2. (if 1. does not work) Moderators can migrate posts away to any site. So if the post is well above the "crap" threshold, feel free to flag for moderator attention and explain why you think it should be migrated and where to.

Comment: I agree that the volume of potential migrations is small, if "don't migrate, ahem, crap" is taken into account.  Much of that is simply because the question is too needlessly localized, and migrating it as would be confusing. E.g., "What's all this stuff about someone's brand of machine? It's just a basic programming question..." -- it is better to close the question and leave a comment.  Limiting migration to moderators allows us to apply that kind of judgement call, and in the end the number of legit migrations doesn't warrant a cookie cutter checkbox interface.

Comment: This answer seems definitive insofar as there's no option to change it at the community level. It makes the site look ragged that there's a trail of dialogs that essentially lead nowhere, so that's too bad. "Being shot down upon arrival" seems appropriate for many of the questions that I've see since they should be marked "duplicate", which we cannot do (with corresponding closure) if they aren't on this site. I think that's too bad, but also beyond this community's control.

Comment: @Brick there is always meta.stackexchange.com for issues beyond the scope of a single site on the network.